# What's the United States plan for post-Assad Syria?

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, syria, civil-war

What strategic plan do US and NATO have IF Assad steps down? Are they trying to replace the Assad regime with a more 'pro' western regime? I'm hoping it doesn't turn into another Iraq/Afghanistan.

Comment: The cynic in me is convinced that the plans is "current administration leaves and they don't need to care post that".

Comment: Do you think if the US government had any plan, they would let us know? What kind of answer are you seeking here? Primarily opinion-based answers?

Comment: @Rathony, Well, we know the US wants a pro western government. Whether it would be a dictatorship or democracy has yet to be seen

Comment: @Killer066 - what is your basis of asserting "the US wants a pro western government"? They clearly didn't care either way in Gaza elections, or when supporting Islamist-won elections in Egypt (and harrassing Al-Sisi), or supporting about-as-far-as-you-can-be-anti-Western-and-still-be-in-NATO Edrogan full tilt

Comment: I'd say their plan is to muddle along hoping for a sudden outbreak of democracy.  Hey, it worked in Tunisia!

Comment: @Brythan - i vote for you for SecState. Or SecDef

Comment: It is very unlikely Russia (a staunch Assad alley) will let the regime change. I have many close Syrian friends who were effected by the war. Most of them told me they just want peace.

Comment: There is a solution of partitioning (or federalizing) Syria, and let Shiites, Sunnis, Christians, the Druze, the Kurds have their own (separate) nations, like [how the French did](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/French_Mandate_for_Syria_and_the_Lebanon_map_en.svg) when Syria was under French control. After all, Iraq and Syria are man-made nations, created by the Ottomans, French and British. However, this is not necessarily a US plan.

Comment: At this point I doubt deposing Al-Assad is on the table. There is no point in going to a peace conference to propose a deal the other part (Putin or Al-Assad himself) has nothing to win with. I would think of end of hostilities, general amnesty & safety ensurance and some measure of local self-government -inside the Syrian state- for the regions most opposed to him (e.g. Kurds).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no evidence the US or NATO would be responsible for figuring out the future government in syria.

Comment: @DylanChensky: Turkey and Iran will *never* allow an independent Kurdistan.

Comment: @SoylentGray The US is involving itself in a war to overthrow the existing government of Syria. Explaining to the public their plans for how to do that and what its goals are is an essential part of selling that war to the public. This sort of question is precisely what this board is for.

Comment: @SoylentGray A major world power's plans or expectations around a world event seems pretty well on topic. It happens that the answer is something like "I hope something, but we don't know anything yet", but this is closer to a duplicate of the ["why did we bomb them"](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/17997/what-incentives-or-stated-motives-did-the-us-have-to-attack-syria) than to being off topic.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt - The problem with the question is not that the base subject is off topic, but that the question is of the type, what will you do when you stop beating your wife?  It assumes that you are doing something wrong, and that you have an obligation to plan your actions that you will take when you stop doing that bad thing.

Comment: @SoylentGray I'm not sure where fault or responsibility come into it. If you drop the fluff on the question it's about international effects of a succession.

Comment: If you drop the fluff off of it then it would be on topic.  Its still got all the fluff that makes it off topic

Comment: @SJuan76 - Could you post this as an answer, please?

Comment: I'm voting to close as "primarily opinion based". We can't really know what US officials are planning. We could answer with what they say their plans are, but that isn't the same thing. Additionally, all three of the answers posted are heavily opinion-based, which supports this question being opinion based itself.

Comment: Judging from what they did to Libya, I would say there is no plan.